# Python - Logging in to web scrape with unnamed input tag for username/password

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, tags, mechanize

We wrote a code to do web scraping on a website protected by a username/password. The problem is that the tag controlling the username/password has no name and no control. Is there an possible workaround?
Here is the HTML code for the password input (same layout for the username):

```
   input class="Bom_loging_input" id="smspassword" type="password" placeholder="请输入密码">
```

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()

br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
br.open('https://www.bom.ai/yunext/STM8S903K3T6C.html')

br.select_form('smsloginform')

password_field = br.form.find_control(id="companyName")

print(password_field)
#password_field.value = "CompanyName"

br['companyName'] = ''
br['accountName'] = ''
br['smspassword'] = '' 
sub = br.submit()
print(sub.geturl())
```

Answer (score 0):

Never worked with Mechanize, but you probably need to simulate a post with the name being the id. You can check that opening the website in your browser, open the network tab and submit the login request. You will see which type of request is done by the browser and replicate on your side.